# Parse - Restrict fields returned on included relation

Tags: rest, curl, parse-platform

Is it possible to restrict the fields returned by Parse on a related field to the object being requested?

The [Parse docs](https://parse.com/docs/rest#queries-constraints) explain how you can restrict the fields returned by a GET request by passing a list of field names to the `keys` property.

> You can restrict the fields returned by passing `keys` a comma-separated list. To retrieve documents that contain only the `score` and `playerName` fields (and also special built-in fields such as `objectId`, `createdAt`, and `updatedAt`):

```
curl -X GET \
     -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: [APP_KEY]" \
     -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: [REST_KEY]" \
     -G \
     --data-urlencode 'keys=score,playerName' \
     https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

So this would return me the `GameScore` objects with only the `score` and `playerName` field present. I'm not interested in the other fields on the `GameScore` object.

Parse also allow you to include the data within a relation object by passing the relation name to the `includes` property. So lets say I have a `User` that has a relation to a `GameScore` class via a field called `gameScore`.

```
curl -X GET \
     -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: [APP_KEY]" \
     -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: [REST_KEY]" \
     -G \
     --data-urlencode 'include=gameScore' \
     https://api.parse.com/1/classes/User
```

This would return the `User` and ALL the fields present within the `gameScore` object.

The question I have is, can I combine the two to make a GET request for a `User`, include the `gameScore` relation but restrict the fields returned on the included `gameScore` object so it only returns the `score` field?

I would expect something like this to work:

```
curl -X GET \
     -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: [APP_KEY]" \
     -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: [REST_KEY]" \
     -G \
     --data-urlencode 'keys=gameScore.score' \
     --data-urlencode 'include=gameScore' \
     https://api.parse.com/1/classes/User
```

Unfortunately I get an error returned stating

> {"code":105,"error":"invalid field name: gameScore.score"}

From this I presume that it is not possible to restrict fields on included relations?

Comment: Try with `include=gameScore.score keys=gameScore` or maybe without `keys` field.

Comment: I do not think this is supported. I am curious why this feature is important to you. Are you trying to save network bandwidth?

Comment: One reason is API calls to the server and I guess indirectly bandwidth. I can work around this no problem. I just thought I'd see if I was missing anything before doing so.

Comment: @knshn Unfortunately that doesn't work as the include is expecting a relationship type. Error: `{"code":102,"error":"field score cannot be included because it is not a pointer to another object"}`

Comment: Ah ok, I thought it would work. Thanks for trying and letting me know.

Comment: Same problem here. Use case: User is the relation I want to return but I don't want to expose the user's email address to the client side to protect them from spam etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution in the end was to write a custom cloud code method that removed the fields before returning it back to the client.